# Azure App Service - Python/Flask/CSRF: Affinity Cookie?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, csrf-token

Currently, I am utilizing Flask-WTF CSRF protection in my Python Flask App Service which is scaled out to 4 instances.  Azure offers an Affinity cookie option to ensure users stay connected to the same instance if required.  However, azure recommends disabling the Affinity Cookie for better performance in stateless apps.  My question:  Is the affinity cookie required so that users no not experience CSRF token issues or is the CSRF token stored in the session.

Currently the sessions are shared across all instances with no issues and the secret key stored and retrieved from my key vault as needed.

Flask==2.2.2
Flask_WTF==1.1.1

I currently have enabled, but want to maximize performance. I expect users to work across all instances with no issued.